# Вычислить принадлежность точки с заданными координатами квадрату

Tags: python

Принадлежит ли точка с координатами (a, b) квадрату, центр которого находится в точке (0,0), а длина стороны равна 10?

```
print("Введите координаты точки не более 5 и не меньше -5(по условию задачи).")
a = int(input("a = "))
b = int(input("b = "))
c = int(5)
d = int(-5)
c1 = int(-5)
d1 = int(5)
if c1<= a <= c and d1>= b >= d:
    print("Точка принадлежит квадрату.")
else:
    print("Точка  не принадлежит квадрату.")
```

Вот только в точке a = -3 b = 4,пишет что точка принадлежит,а так быть не должно вроде как.

Comment: Почему не должно? От [-5,-5] до [5,5] все точки принадлежат квадрату

Comment: Шо, [опять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1353908/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83)? Вас же уже поправляли.